# Matlab: Semilogx() doesn't plot all values

Tags: matlab, plot, axis

When I run this script in Matlab, the value at Point 3 gets ignored.
Why? And how can I change it?

```
x=[0 3 24];
y=[88.3 89.17 90.92];
semilogx(x,y,'-x')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The point that is being ignored is the *first*, not the third. The reason is that you are using a logarithmic *x*-axis, and the first point has *x*=0, so the logarithm is −∞.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Could solve the Problem using eps instead. Thanks.

Comment: @ElNico But note that using `eps` will change the scale of the _x_ axis a lot, and will introduce an arbitrary value. When you have `0` it may be a better idea to avoid a logarithmic axis

Comment: I noticed that too, when I plot it with a grid. Try to find a solution with an offset. Not sure what else to use, because bigger values are comming and linear doesn't work for it.

Comment: @ElNico I've had that problem in the past. I solved it using `semilogx(1+x, ...)`. But that was because `1+x` had a definite meaning in my specific problem, and so using it was justifiable. It may not be your case